# Does Passenger 3 support Rails 2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I would like to have the Passenger module updated on one of our webservers. Sadly, we have a legacy app running on that machine, which was build using Rails 2.1. Are there any problems to expect running Rails 2.1 on Passenger 3? Rails uses Rack since version 2.3, I think.

We currently use Passenger 2.2.11 (installed with apt-get on Debian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it myself, since there was no answer so far. Rails 2.1 works fine with Passenger 3.0.9.

Comment: Did you need to create a rackup file (config.ru) for your app?